# TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement

Tags: jquery

Hola a todos tengo un error el cual esta en el titulo, el caso es que quiero enviar datos a traves de un Javascript pero salta este error la version de Jquery es algo antigua es la `jquery-1.11.1.min.js`, no la puedo cambiar debido a que corro el riesgo de fastidiar todo el programa ya hecho años atras, el codigo que tengo es este

**HTML**

```
   <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="add_iva" type="checkbox" checked="true">A&ntilde;adir IVA </label></td>
   <td>IVA (<span class="obj_iva">21%</span>)</td>
   <td><span class="valor_iva">{$objeto.productos.importe_iva_formateado}</span> &euro;</td>
```

(y en la misma pagina)
**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    obj_iva_ant=$('.obj_iva').text();
    valor_iva=$('.valor_iva').text();
    valor_total = $('.total').text();
    /*EDIT IVA*/
    $('.add_iva').on( 'change', function() {

        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $('.obj_iva').text(obj_iva_ant);
            $('.valor_iva').text(valor_iva);
            $('.total').text(valor_total);

        } else {
            $('.total').text(Math.round(valor_total-valor_iva));
            obj_iva_cero =$('.obj_iva').text("0%");
            valor_iva_cero =$('.valor_iva').text("0.00");
            iva_bool=$(this).is(':checked');
            // console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
            $.post('edit_iva.php',{valor_iva_cero:valor_iva_cero,iva_bool:iva_bool},
            function(response){
                $("#rta_iva").text(response);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

El error va directamente el `$.post` y la verdad no entiendo el por que

Comment: Creo que los tiros van por el 'valor_iva_cero = $('.valor_iva').text("0.00");'. Si no me equivoco, hacer esto te devuelve un objeto jquery y no el valor de texto, asi que estas enviando por post algo que no permite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.valor_iva').text("0.00")` retorna un objecto jquery por lo que cuando envias ese resultado por el post te fallara ya que no puedes enviar ese tipo de objecto.

Intenta obtener el texto otra vez al momento de enviar el parametro:

```
//...
$.post('edit_iva.php',{valor_iva_cero:$('.valor_iva').text(), iva_bool:iva_bool}, function(response){
                $("#rta_iva").text(response);
});
```